Fontawesome svg-icons in openlayers
I know similar questions have been asked before but their answers don't help me.
I'm trying to use Fontawesome-Icons as markers in an Openlayers map like this:
const svg = `
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                <path d="M320 64c0-12.6-7.4-24-18.9-29.2s-25-3.1-34.4 5.3L131.8 160H64c-35.3 0-64 28.7-64 64v64c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h67.8L266.7 471.9c9.4 8.4 22.9 10.4 34.4 5.3S320 460.6 320 448V64z"/></svg>
            `;
const svgUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + svg;
let measurePointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({              
        src: svgUrl,
        scale: 1
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: "IO",
        offsetY: 25,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});

the text part of the style appears on the map correctly but the Icon does not. No errors.
I've been looking for a solution for over an hour now but can't find anything that helps. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here it would be highly appreciated.

The simplest solution is to use the JavaScript encodeURIComponent method:
const svg = `
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                <path d="M320 64c0-12.6-7.4-24-18.9-29.2s-25-3.1-34.4 5.3L131.8 160H64c-35.3 0-64 28.7-64 64v64c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h67.8L266.7 471.9c9.4 8.4 22.9 10.4 34.4 5.3S320 460.6 320 448V64z"/></svg>
            `;
const svgUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);
let measurePointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({              
        src: svgUrl,
        scale: 1
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: "IO",
        offsetY: 25,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});


Thank you for your input! Both this and Danny's solution work if i put the resulting url in an img element for testing. The image gets displayed as expected. on the map on the other hand, still no icons. any ideas what else could cause this?

To be drawn reliably to a canvas the SVG must have width and height attributes as well as viewBox.

that was it. such a simple thing... thank you!

You have to replace all double quotes, because the src attribute itself is enclosed in double quotes
Note: if your SVG uses # in colors or ids, you have to escape that character with the string %23
because a # has special meaning in a (data)URI


img { height:160px }
<script>
let svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.-->
             <path d="M320 64c0-12.6-7.4-24-18.9-29.2s-25-3.1-34.4 5.3L131.8 160H64c-35.3 0-64 28.7-64 64v64c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h67.8L266.7 471.9c9.4 8.4 22.9 10.4 34.4 5.3S320 460.6 320 448V64z"/>
           </svg>`;
document.write(`<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,${svg}">`);
svg = svg.replaceAll(`"`,`'`);
document.write(`<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,${svg}">`);
</script>



